# Error in checking-out from bit-bucket in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I am using Pycharm with bitbucket. Using check-out version control via git, I get the following error:

```
Error: Repository URL is a malformed URL or non-existent directory
```

So far everything was working fine. Any ideas whats this about as I cannot find any thing about this specific error online?

Note: I have two repositories. One is just a test one where test different things and one is my proper production repository. The checkout is working with the testing one and used to work with the production one but it's not anymore. The usual actions work fine such as git commit, git pull, or push etc.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

**UPDATE: It is somehow resolved now. I would still like to know what causes this problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to remove `git clone` from the first field

Comment: Just noticed that actually, it was the reason. A stupid mistake on my side.